# How Can JQuery be embedded in the <body> and </body> Tags in Joomla 3.1?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, joomla

I've added this code below to my default.php file in joomla 3.1.

```
<?php
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
JFactory::getDocument()->addScript(JURI::root().'template/mytemplate/js/jquery.min.js'); 
?>
```

This only embeds the script inside the head tags.

Is there a way i can make it appear in the body tag?

Comment: Why do you desire this?

Comment: the script am running only works if in the body tags.

Comment: you might want to post a question about that because based on my knowledge of how Javascript works in a browser, there is no situation where a script would only 'work' if placed in a certain area of the document. Scripts are parsed sequentially before the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment on the other question, you can't import jQuery in the `<body>` tag using the `JHtml()` or `JFactory` method. These methods add the script to the `<head>` tag automatically.

The only way you can achieve what you want is to use `<script>` tags, however please see how I have done it:

```
<?php
  // load jQuery, if not loaded before
  if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
     JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
     ?>
     <script>
        jQuery.noConflict();
     </script>
     <script src="<?php echo JUri::root(). 'template/mytemplate/js/jquery.min.js'; ?>"></script>
<?php
  }
?>
```

This basically checks to see if jQuery is being imported already and if not, then it imports it. Add this code to the **index.php** in your template folder.

If you see the following in your **index.php**:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

then remove it.

Please bare in mind that this is not a recommended method however it's the only way that I know of to import it after the `<body>` tag.

Also note that if you ever update your template, then your changes will be lost

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo JURI::root();?>templates/<?php echo $app->getTemplate();?>/js/jquery.min.js" />
```

Into your template index.php

or

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo JURI::root();?>templates/mytemplate/js/jquery.min.js" />
```

into any template override

I can't see the benefit of doing this though at all.

Comment: Don't forget to take into account that there might already be a copy of jQuery already being imported from elsewhere. As you already probably know, multiple copies of jQuery can result in things going tits up